# Reading GBIF checklist meta data in R

Tags: r

I would like to get occurrence records from GBIF for all invasive species in several regions of interest.
I’m using the GRIIS checklists from [ISSG](https://www.gbif.org/publisher/cdef28b1-db4e-4c58-aa71-3c5238c2d0b5) to identify which species are listed as Invasive in a given country. This is how I’ve been doing it so far:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rgbif)

# Setting credentials to access GBIF-API
Sys.setenv(GBIF_USER = 'user') 
Sys.setenv(GBIF_PWD = 'password') 
Sys.setenv(GBIF_EMAIL = 'email')

# This will list all checklists from ISSG 

ISSG <- dataset_search(publishingOrg = 'cdef28b1-db4e-4c58-aa71-3c5238c2d0b5',   
                       type = 'checklist')

# I will now filter according to administration/country
# This is an example with only two countries, though I have much more
admin <- c('India', 'Malaysia')

# This will return the checklist for 'admin' only
ISSG_admin <- ISSG$data[grep(pattern = paste(names, collapse="|"), 
                             ISSG$data$datasetTitle), ]

# datasetKey(s) for the intended checklists 
datasetKeys <- unique(proj_ISSG$datasetKey)

# Return all the taxon listed by GRIIS as being either invasive or introduced 
proj_ISSG_list <- lapply(datasetKeys, 
        function(x) name_usage(datasetKey = x, limit = 10000))

# From object 'proj_ISSG_list' I can easily download all the records for each taxon listed in the GRIIS checklist
# Example for India removing entries where ‘nubKey’ or ‘species’ are NA    
keys <- na.omit(proj_ISSG_list[[1]]$data[!is.na(proj_ISSG_list[[1]]$data$species), ]$nubKey) # returns GBIF backbone key

# The following will return occurrence points for all species listed in the GRIIS checklist for India 
# This will take some time to run and doesn’t produce the intended results, as explained below
# res <- sapply(keys,
#               function(x) occ_download_queue(occ_download(pred('taxonKey', x),
#                                                           pred('hasCoordinate', TRUE),
#                                                           pred('country', 'IN'), # iso2c country code for India
#                                                           )))
```

Now, the issue is that this will download occurrence for all taxon identified by the GRIIS database, meaning species that are either invasive or introduced (n = 2057).

```
length(keys)
[1] 2057 # 2057 taxon
```

**However, I’m only interested in species that are invasive**. This information is provided by column ‘isInvaisve’ in file ‘speciesprofile.txt’ (see below) inside the Darwin Core Archive (DwCA) which can be [directly downloaded from GBIF](https://cloud.gbif.org/griis/archive.do?r=griis-india).

```
# Importing species profile from DwCA after download
sp_profile_GRIIS <- read.table("path/dwca-griis-india-v1.5/speciesprofile.txt",
header = TRUE)
head(sp_profile_GRIIS)
     id isInvasive     habitat
1 80500       Null Terrestrial
2 80501       Null Terrestrial
3 80502       Null Terrestrial
4 80503       Null Terrestrial
5 80504       Null Terrestrial
6 80505       Null Terrestrial
```

I can get species profile directly from GBIF for the taxon `keys` as follows:

```
sp_profile <- 
  proj_ISSG_list[[1]]$data %>% 
  pull(key) %>%
  map_dfr(., function(x) {
    profile_details <-name_usage(x, data = "speciesProfile")
    return(profile_details$data)
    }
    )
print(sp_profile)
    taxonKey habitat    
       <int> <chr>      
 1 160887913 Marine     
 2 160887914 Host       
 3 160887925 Host       
 4 160887926 Terrestrial
 5 160887927 Host       
 6 160887934 Marine     
 7 160887937 Terrestrial
 8 160887940 Freshwater 
 9 160887947 Marine     
10 160887951 Marine     
# … with 2,166 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

However, this does not retreive information about invasiveness as in `sp_profile_GRIIS`.

Finally, as you can see, from the 2057 taxon listed in `keys`, only 283 are identified as invasive in the GRIIS checklist

```
# Number of Invasive species listed for India in GRIIS
nrow(sp_profile_GRIIS %>% filter(isInvasive == 'Invasive'))
[1] 282
```

If I could find a way to directly filter the taxon that are actually listed as invasive in the ‘speciesprofile.txt’ available in the DwCA it would be great. Of course, I can download the DwCA one by one from GBIF, read the ‘speciesprofile.txt’ files and filter species identified as invasive, but this won’t be efficient if we are interested in checklist from many different countries, especially if I need to repeat for a different group of countries.

Any advice would be great. I guess that even a way of downloading the DwCA through R would already be helpful, as I could then loop for the different countries.

Comment: I guess you have to join `speciesprofile.txt` data with `taxon.txt` data on `id`, then filter out your `proj_ISSG_list` based on `scientificName` from the above join. BTW, when downloading the occurrence data please remember to get the occurrence data for synonyms as well.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I know I can do that, but is there a way I can load those files directly in R without downloading the DwCA archive one by one from GBIF first? I would like to write a R routine to get this information from multiple checklists and make it reproducible.

Comment: Don't know, you have to check GBIF API / `{gbifR}`, if DwCA is accessible there. Never checked that by myself. Otherwise I will grab https://cloud.gbif.org/griis/ with `{httr}` package and download and process the requested `zip's` by R. And then made the joins/subsets/etc.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko thanks for the suggestion, that will be a nice workaround. I probably can work with the URL patterns and 'paste' functions, unless you can suggest a nice way to direxi grab the URL for the desired checklists. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my attempt:

All GRIIS lists are listed in their `rss` feed, so:

```r
feed <- tidyRSS::tidyfeed("https://cloud.gbif.org/griis/rss.do")
#> GET request successful. Parsing...
```

Now, apply your country specific filter, like:

```r
a <- feed |>
  subset(grepl("Poland|France", item_title))
```

We are interested in links to country-specific pages, like `https://cloud.gbif.org/griis/resource?r=griis-poland` so, we have to take `item_link` (here just an example, in your case you have to ran it in loop/apply() ):

```r
a[3, "item_link"]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   item_link                                           
#>   <chr>                                               
#> 1 https://cloud.gbif.org/griis/resource?r=griis-poland
```

Now we have to get country-specific page content and search for download link to zip file, like:

```r
url <- a[3, "item_link"][[1]]
html <- rvest::read_html(url)
b <- html |>
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/table') |>
  rvest::html_children()

url <- b[[1]] |>
  rvest::html_element("a") |>
  rvest::html_attr(name = "href")
```

And finally download zip file:

```r
download.file(url, destfile = "data/ala.zip")
unzip("data/ala.zip", exdir = "data")
```

Having it extracted we are able to read and join both tables:

```r
species <- read.csv("data/speciesprofile.txt", sep = "\t") |>
  subset(isInvasive == "Invasive")
taxon <- read.csv("data/taxon.txt", sep = "\t")

species |>
  dplyr::left_join(taxon, by = c("id" = "taxonID"))
#>       id isInvasive                    habitat  id.y
#> 1  84557   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 84557
#> 2  84587   Invasive                Terrestrial 84587
#> 3  84591   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 84591
#> 4  84599   Invasive                     Marine 84599
#> 5  84628   Invasive                       Host 84628
#> 6  84652   Invasive                       Host 84652
#> 7  84671   Invasive                Terrestrial 84671
#> 8  84673   Invasive                Terrestrial 84673
#> 9  84674   Invasive                Terrestrial 84674
#> 10 84721   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 84721
#> 11 84728   Invasive                       Host 84728
#> 12 84740   Invasive                Terrestrial 84740
#> 13 84757   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 84757
#> 14 84813   Invasive                Terrestrial 84813
#> 15 84822   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 84822
#> 16 84830   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 84830
#> 17 84868   Invasive                 Freshwater 84868
#> 18 84875   Invasive                Terrestrial 84875
#> 19 84883   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 84883
#> 20 84884   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 84884
#> 21 84952   Invasive                Terrestrial 84952
#> 22 84963   Invasive                 Freshwater 84963
#> 23 84966   Invasive Freshwater|Brackish|Marine 84966
#> 24 85006   Invasive                 Freshwater 85006
#> 25 85032   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 85032
#> 26 85073   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 85073
#> 27 85089   Invasive                 Freshwater 85089
#> 28 85145   Invasive                     Marine 85145
#> 29 85236   Invasive                     Marine 85236
#> 30 85275   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 85275
#> 31 85292   Invasive                Terrestrial 85292
#> 32 85342   Invasive                 Freshwater 85342
#> 33 85343   Invasive                 Freshwater 85343
#> 34 85356   Invasive                Terrestrial 85356
#> 35 85398   Invasive                Terrestrial 85398
#> 36 85433   Invasive                Terrestrial 85433
#> 37 85434   Invasive                Terrestrial 85434
#> 38 85557   Invasive                     Marine 85557
#> 39 85563   Invasive                Terrestrial 85563
#> 40 85565   Invasive                Terrestrial 85565
#> 41 85591   Invasive Freshwater|Brackish|Marine 85591
#> 42 85593   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 85593
#> 43 85609   Invasive                Terrestrial 85609
#> 44 85662   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 85662
#> 45 85689   Invasive                Terrestrial 85689
#> 46 85697   Invasive                Terrestrial 85697
#> 47 85701   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 85701
#> 48 85702   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 85702
#> 49 85739   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 85739
#> 50 85806   Invasive                 Freshwater 85806
#> 51 85857   Invasive        Freshwater|Brackish 85857
#> 52 85866   Invasive                 Freshwater 85866
#> 53 85877   Invasive                 Freshwater 85877
#> 54 85880   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 85880
#> 55 85882   Invasive Freshwater|Brackish|Marine 85882
#> 56 85897   Invasive                       Host 85897
#> 57 85898   Invasive                       Host 85898
#> 58 85901   Invasive                 Freshwater 85901
#> 59 85940   Invasive                Terrestrial 85940
#> 60 85947   Invasive                Terrestrial 85947
#> 61 86018   Invasive Freshwater|Brackish|Marine 86018
#> 62 86061   Invasive                 Freshwater 86061
#> 63 86179   Invasive     Terrestrial|Freshwater 86179
#> 64 86248   Invasive                       Host 86248
#>                                                                             scientificName
#> 1                                                    Alopochen aegyptiaca (Linnaeus, 1766)
#> 2                                                                 Ambrosia polystachya DC.
#> 3                                                       Ameiurus nebulosus (Lesueur, 1819)
#> 4                                                     Amphibalanus improvisus Darwin, 1854
#> 5  Anguillicoloides crassus (Kuwahara, Niimi & Itagaki, 1974) Moravec & Taraschewski, 1988
#> 6                                                              Aphanomyces astaci Schikora
#> 7                                                           Arion distinctus Mabille, 1868
#> 8                                                        Arion lusitanicus J.Mabille, 1868
#> 9                                                             Arion rufus (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 10                                                    Babka gymnotrachelus (Kessler, 1857)
#> 11                          Batrachochytrium dendrobatidis Longcore, Pessier & D.K.Nichols
#> 12                                                            Bison bison (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 13                                                      Branta canadensis (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 14                                               Cameraria ohridella Deschka & Dimic, 1986
#> 15                                                         Carassius gibelio (Bloch, 1782)
#> 16                                                                      Carex brizoides L.
#> 17                                                     Cercopagis pengoi (Ostroumov, 1891)
#> 18                                                            Cervus nippon Temminck, 1838
#> 19                                             Chelicorophium curvispinum (G.O.Sars, 1895)
#> 20                                                    Chelydra serpentina (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 21                                                              Columba livia Gmelin, 1789
#> 22                                                  Corbicula fluminea (O.F.MÃ¼ller, 1774)
#> 23                                                          Coregonus peled (Gmelin, 1789)
#> 24                                            Ctenopharyngodon idella (Valenciennes, 1844)
#> 25                                                          Cyprinus carpio Linnaeus, 1758
#> 26                                                Dikerogammarus villosus (Sowinsky, 1894)
#> 27                                                     Dreissena polymorpha (Pallas, 1771)
#> 28                                                Eriocheir sinensis H.Milne Edwards, 1853
#> 29                                                          Gammarus tigrinus Sexton, 1939
#> 30                                                Graptemys pseudogeographica (Gray, 1831)
#> 31                                                        Harmonia axyridis (Pallas, 1773)
#> 32                                        Hypophthalmichthys molitrix (Valenciennes, 1844)
#> 33                                           Hypophthalmichthys nobilis (Richardson, 1845)
#> 34                                                                Impatiens parviflora DC.
#> 35                                 Lasius neglectus van Loon, Boomsma & AndrÃ¡sfalvy, 1990
#> 36                                                         Limacus flavus (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 37                                                            Limax maximus Linnaeus, 1758
#> 38                                                       Mnemiopsis leidyi A.Agassiz, 1865
#> 39                                                   Monomorium pharaonis (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 40                                                             Mus musculus Linnaeus, 1758
#> 41                                                   Neogobius melanostomus (Pallas, 1814)
#> 42                                                         Neovison vison (Schreber, 1777)
#> 43                                                   Nyctereutes procyonoides (Gray, 1834)
#> 44                                                     Ondatra zibethicus (Linnaeus, 1766)
#> 45                                                             Ovis ammon (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 46                                                    Oxychilus draparnaudi (H.Beck, 1837)
#> 47                                                       Oxyura jamaicensis (Gmelin, 1789)
#> 48                                                   Pacifastacus leniusculus (Dana, 1852)
#> 49                                                        Perccottus glenii Dybowski, 1877
#> 50                                                    Piaractus brachypomus (Cuvier, 1818)
#> 51                                                  Pontogammarus robustoides (Sars, 1894)
#> 52                                                   Potamopyrgus antipodarum (Gray, 1843)
#> 53                                                      Procambarus clarkii (Girard, 1852)
#> 54                                                          Procyon lotor (Linnaeus, 1758)
#> 55                                                 Proterorhinus marmoratus (Pallas, 1814)
#> 56                         Pseudodactylogyrus anguillae (Yin & Sproston, 1948) Gusev, 1965
#> 57                                                 Pseudodactylogyrus bini (Kikuchi, 1929)
#> 58                                         Pseudorasbora parva (Temminck & Schlegel, 1846)
#> 59                                                    Rattus norvegicus (Berkenhout, 1769)
#> 60                                                              Reynoutria japonica Houtt.
#> 61                                                  Salvelinus fontinalis (Mitchill, 1814)
#> 62                                                      Sinanodonta woodiana (I.Lea, 1834)
#> 63                                                  Trachemys scripta elegans (Wied, 1838)
#> 64                                              Varroa destructor Anderson & Trueman, 2000
#>    acceptedNameUsage   kingdom          phylum            class           order
#> 1                     Animalia        Chordata             Aves    Anseriformes
#> 2                      Plantae    Tracheophyta    Magnoliopsida       Asterales
#> 3                     Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii    Siluriformes
#> 4                     Animalia      Arthropoda      Maxillopoda        Sessilia
#> 5                     Animalia        Nematoda      Secernentea       Spirurida
#> 6                    Chromista        Oomycota     Peronosporea  Saprolegniales
#> 7                     Animalia        Mollusca       Gastropoda Stylommatophora
#> 8                     Animalia        Mollusca       Gastropoda Stylommatophora
#> 9                     Animalia        Mollusca       Gastropoda Stylommatophora
#> 10                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii     Perciformes
#> 11                       Fungi Chytridiomycota Chytridiomycetes  Rhizophydiales
#> 12                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia    Artiodactyla
#> 13                    Animalia        Chordata             Aves    Anseriformes
#> 14                    Animalia      Arthropoda          Insecta     Lepidoptera
#> 15                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Cypriniformes
#> 16                     Plantae    Tracheophyta       Liliopsida          Poales
#> 17                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Branchiopoda     Diplostraca
#> 18                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia    Artiodactyla
#> 19                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Malacostraca       Amphipoda
#> 20                    Animalia        Chordata         Reptilia      Testudines
#> 21                    Animalia        Chordata             Aves   Columbiformes
#> 22                    Animalia        Mollusca         Bivalvia        Venerida
#> 23                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Salmoniformes
#> 24                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Cypriniformes
#> 25                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Cypriniformes
#> 26                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Malacostraca       Amphipoda
#> 27                    Animalia        Mollusca         Bivalvia           Myida
#> 28                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Malacostraca        Decapoda
#> 29                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Malacostraca       Amphipoda
#> 30                    Animalia        Chordata         Reptilia      Testudines
#> 31                    Animalia      Arthropoda          Insecta      Coleoptera
#> 32                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Cypriniformes
#> 33                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Cypriniformes
#> 34                     Plantae    Tracheophyta    Magnoliopsida        Ericales
#> 35                    Animalia      Arthropoda          Insecta     Hymenoptera
#> 36                    Animalia        Mollusca       Gastropoda Stylommatophora
#> 37                    Animalia        Mollusca       Gastropoda Stylommatophora
#> 38                    Animalia      Ctenophora      Tentaculata          Lobata
#> 39                    Animalia      Arthropoda          Insecta     Hymenoptera
#> 40                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia        Rodentia
#> 41                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii     Perciformes
#> 42                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia       Carnivora
#> 43                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia       Carnivora
#> 44                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia        Rodentia
#> 45                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia    Artiodactyla
#> 46                    Animalia        Mollusca       Gastropoda Stylommatophora
#> 47                    Animalia        Chordata             Aves    Anseriformes
#> 48                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Malacostraca        Decapoda
#> 49                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii     Perciformes
#> 50                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Characiformes
#> 51                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Malacostraca       Amphipoda
#> 52                    Animalia        Mollusca       Gastropoda Littorinimorpha
#> 53                    Animalia      Arthropoda     Malacostraca        Decapoda
#> 54                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia       Carnivora
#> 55                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii     Perciformes
#> 56                    Animalia Platyhelminthes        Monogenea  Dactylogyridea
#> 57                    Animalia Platyhelminthes        Monogenea  Dactylogyridea
#> 58                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Cypriniformes
#> 59                    Animalia        Chordata         Mammalia        Rodentia
#> 60                     Plantae    Tracheophyta    Magnoliopsida  Caryophyllales
#> 61                    Animalia        Chordata   Actinopterygii   Salmoniformes
#> 62                    Animalia        Mollusca         Bivalvia        Unionida
#> 63                    Animalia        Chordata         Reptilia      Testudines
#> 64                    Animalia      Arthropoda        Arachnida    Mesostigmata
#>                  family  taxonRank taxonomicStatus
#> 1              Anatidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 2            Asteraceae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 3           Ictaluridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 4             Balanidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 5       Anguillicolidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 6       Leptolegniaceae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 7             Arionidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 8             Arionidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 9             Arionidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 10             Gobiidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 11                         SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 12              Bovidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 13             Anatidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 14       Gracillariidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 15           Cyprinidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 16           Cyperaceae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 17         Cercopagidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 18             Cervidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 19          Corophiidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 20          Chelydridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 21           Columbidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 22            Cyrenidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 23           Salmonidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 24           Cyprinidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 25           Cyprinidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 26           Gammaridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 27         Dreissenidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 28   Pseudothelphusidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 29           Gammaridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 30             Emydidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 31        Coccinellidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 32           Cyprinidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 33           Cyprinidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 34        Balsaminaceae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 35           Formicidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 36            Limacidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 37            Limacidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 38         Bolinopsidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 39           Formicidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 40              Muridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 41             Gobiidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 42           Mustelidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 43              Canidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 44           Cricetidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 45              Bovidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 46          Oxychilidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 47             Anatidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 48            Astacidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 49        Odontobutidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 50        Serrasalmidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 51      Pontogammaridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 52             Tateidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 53           Cambaridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 54          Procyonidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 55             Gobiidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 56 Pseudodactylogyridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 57 Pseudodactylogyridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 58           Cyprinidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 59              Muridae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 60         Polygonaceae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 61           Salmonidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 62            Unionidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 63             Emydidae SUBSPECIES        ACCEPTED
#> 64            Varroidae    SPECIES        ACCEPTED
```

Now, having `scientificName(s)` you are able to search for occurrence.

<sup>Created on 2023-07-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll try this approach today and will upvote it afterwards!

Comment: that's working, amazing! I would just just highlight that apparently you need to add `mode = 'wb'`  in windows machines in `download.file(url, destfile = "data/ala.zip", mode = 'wb')` otherwise you get an invalid `zip` file. I also added some code to preserve original `DwCA` filename. I'll edit my question for a complete example.

Comment: Glad it works for you :). And yes, you might be right about 'wb' in Windows. BTW, don't know your requirements regarding the invasive species list accuracy, but be carefull. Have checked it for Poland and it's far away from completness.